# Ignore wildcard

Tags: soql

I want my SOQL to return ONLY those objects which have `__c`. However when I tried below it even returns me objects like `ContentWorkspaceDoc`, `PushTopic`, `Topic` etc. It assumes underscore as placeholder.

```
select id, QualifiedApiName, DeveloperName 
from EntityDefinition 
where QualifiedApiName like '%__c'
```

How can we exclude them?

Comment: You're supposed to use `\ ` to escape a `%` or `_`, but I think this particular field may be "broken", perhaps because it's not "really" a text field, or there's a platform bug. I can't seem to get this field to behave correctly.